# Arguments are different! wanted

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

sorry for this question which has been yet answered before. But so far, i didn't resolve my issue.
Ok let's say i have a class below that i want to test the method checkMail():

```
public class SupplierRosServiceImpl implements SupplierRosService {

    @Autowired
    private OpeSupplierService supplierService;

    @Autowired
    private OpeSupplierMapper opeSupplierMapper;

    @Autowired
    private OpeSupplierTraceService supplierTraceService;


    private SupplierServiceMapper supplierServiceMapper;

    @DubboReference
    private IdAppService idAppService;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> countStatus(GeneralEnter enter) {
    List<CountByStatusResult> statusResults = supplierServiceMapper.countStatus(enter);
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (CountByStatusResult item : statusResults) {
        map.put(item.getStatus(), item.getTotalCount());
    }
    for (SupplierStatusEnum status : SupplierStatusEnum.values()) {
        if (!map.containsKey(status.getValue())) {
            map.put(status.getValue(), 0);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

    public Boolean checkMail(String mail,String idStr) {
        QueryWrapper<OpeSupplier> wrapper = new QueryWrapper<>();
        wrapper.eq(OpeSupplier.COL_CONTACT_EMAIL, mail);
        wrapper.eq(OpeSupplier.COL_DR, 0);
        if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(idStr)){
          wrapper.ne(OpeSupplier.COL_ID, Long.parseLong(idStr));
        }
       return opeSupplierMapper.selectCount(wrapper) > 0 ? Boolean.FALSE  : Boolean.TRUE;
    }
```

in my test class i have:

```
    class SupplierRosServiceImplTest {

         @InjectMocks
         SupplierRosServiceImpl supplierRosService;

         @Mock
         QueryWrapper queryWrapper;

         @Mock
         private OpeSupplierMapper ope;


         @Test
         void ItShouldCheckMail() {

        //when
        supplierRosService.checkMail("myEmailAdress", "123456");
        //then
        verify(ope).selectCount(queryWrapper);
   }
```

the exception tell : Argument(s) are different! wanted:
ope.selectCount(querywrapper)
Actual invocations have differents arguements:
ope.selectCount(com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.query.QueryWrapper@ba1f559)
someone could tell me how to solve this one ?

Comment: the problem i have is an exception that is thrown in my test . take a look at my post

Answer (score 1):

i resolved my issue. the problem was it to change the implementation detail through passing to my service injection of QueryWrapper thus mock properly this one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the imports in both classes for `QueryWrapper`  if, both are from same package or not, seems imported in test class from different package.

if not then please paste your whole code with imports as well.

Comment: the imports are the same for both test and class